# How to separate extra text after youtube id in youtube url using jquery?

Tags: jquery, youtube

This code is to check Youtube video link is valid or not but  what I need is if user  enter youtube Url in textarea and include some text using space or without space .so how that text should get separated after youtube id,and place in separate variable so please tell me where to change the code to get this.

```
<textarea name="youtube_url"></textarea>

    jQuery("textarea[name*='youtube_url']").blur(function () {
         var target = jQuery(this).val();

                          var regExp = /^.*(youtu\.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=)([^#\&\?]*).*/;
                          var match = target.match(regExp);
                          if (match && match[2].length == 11) {
                             var  videoID  = match[2];
                        }


                    $.ajax({
                        url: "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/" + videoID + "?v=2&alt=json",
                        //dataType: "jsonp",
                        success: function(data) {
                            console.log(data)
                             // $("#result").text(data);
                        },
                        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                                        {
                                            // Handle errors here
                                            alert('ERRORS: ' + textStatus);
                                        }
                    });
                        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Matching the URL

If you are looking to break the url you need to cover even the short urls and embed.

Here is a regex that will work:

`(http(s|):|)\/\/(www\.|)yout(.*?)\/(embed\/|watch.*?v=|)([a-z_A-Z0-9\-]{11})`

Here is a test: [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/wKb4BP/1)

If you want the ID you need the 6-th member. Here is an example

```js
    jQuery("textarea[name*='youtube_url']").blur(function() {
        var target = jQuery(this).val();

        var regExp = /(http(s|):|)\/\/(www\.|)yout(.*?)\/(embed\/|watch.*?v=|)([a-z_A-Z0-9\-]{11})/i;
        var match = target.match(regExp);
        // No need to check if 11 chars, already did that in the Regex
        var videoID = '';

        if (match[6]) {
            videoID = match[6];
        }

        console.log(videoID);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">    </script>
<textarea name="youtube_url"></textarea>
```

If you would like to get the time from the video (if it is pased) you can improve the regex like this:

`(http(s|):|)\/\/(www\.|)yout(.*?)\/(embed\/|watch.*?v=|)([a-z_A-Z0-9\-]{11})(\?t=.*|)`

There in the 7th group you will find the time. This will return the time with a get parameter `?t=` if you want you can isolate the digits only:

`(http(s|):|)\/\/(www\.|)yout(.*?)\/(embed\/|watch.*?v=|)([a-z_A-Z0-9\-]{11})(?:\?t=|)(\d+|)`

### Matching after the url.

Because I didn't get the question in the first time, here is how you would get the text after the URL and also get the URL (video ID).

`(http(s|):|)\/\/(www\.|)yout(.*?)\/(embed\/|watch.*?v=|)([a-z_A-Z0-9\-]{11})(?:\?t=|)(\d+|)([\S\s]*)`

`([\S\s]*)` will capture anything including newlines before and after the url:

```js
jQuery("textarea[name*='youtube_url']").blur(function() {
  var target = jQuery(this).val();

  var regExp = /(http(s|):|)\/\/(www\.|)yout(.*?)\/(embed\/|watch.*?v=|)([a-z_A-Z0-9\-]{11})(?:\?t=|)(\d+|)([\S\s]*)/i;
  var match = target.match(regExp);
  // No need to check if 11 chars, already did that in the Regex
  if (match[6]) {
    var videoID = match[6];
  }
  
  console.log("Video ID:");
  console.log(match[6]);
  console.log("Video start time:");
  console.log(match[7]);
  console.log("After:");
  console.log(match[8]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><strong>Example to try:</strong></p>
<p>https://youtu.be/xcJtL7QggTI?t=73 this a Sony 4k Video starts at 73s</p>
<textarea name="youtube_url"></textarea>
```

Comment: how to get any text typed after url I mean how to separate only text after Url and js fiddle also not working.

Comment: Forgot to include jq. How do you mean only text after url

Comment: suppose https://www.youtube.com/embed/zcsgC39HWry?  is url after this user enter  "this video is for some tutorials  to learn jquery " this kind of description so how to separate this text from Url by jquery and place in variable.

Comment: @faiz If the answer is correct please mark it as solved.